# What can I do when Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't recognize my password?

Tags: grub, login, multi-boot, ubuntu-11.10

Currently I'm dual-booting Ubuntu along side Windows 7. I recently upgraded to 11.10, and everything was going fine for a bit. However, I can no longer log in with my user account. The guest account works fine. I also tried logging in through the command line (Alt+Ctrl+F1), but to no avail. For some reason it doesn't seem to recognize my password anymore.

Also, I no longer see the secondary GRUB screen:

[image: this one]

Instead it will flash a Fatal Error message, then load the GUI. I'm wondering what my options are, I don't have anything important on there that I don't have backed up, so I'd be fine with re-installing Ubuntu entirley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Paul's answer doesn't work, you could boot a LiveCD (of Ubuntu), log in as root to the LiveCD and do this:

```
mount your normal Ubuntu partition (mkdir /mnt/ubuntu && mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/ubuntu)
chroot into it (chroot /mnt/ubuntu)
change your password (passwd my_user)
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold down shift during boot up.  This should cause the grub menu to appear.  Choose the recovery mode, which will drop you into a command prompt.  At the prompt, type

```
passwd <user>
```

Where *user* is your normal userid.  This will prompt to change the password.  Then you can reboot and login as normal.